# Why does Swift malloc() when I'm iterating over a loop?

Tags: arrays, swift, performance, loops

I'm performance-testing a loop in my code and a surprisingly large amount (734ms for a list of 1'000'000 items) is spent in

```
734ms Array.subscript.read
380ms   Array.subscript.getter
223ms     _ArrayBuffer.checkInoutAndNativeTypeCheckedBounds(_:wasNativeTypeChecked:)
 92ms     swift::metadataimpl::ValueWitnesses<swift::metadataimpl::SwiftRetainableBox>::initializeWithCopy(swift::OpaqueValue*, ...
 16ms     _swift_isClassOrObjCExistentialType
  3ms     swift_bridgeObjectRelease
329ms   malloc
```

Anyone have an idea why this is? I'm particularly surprised why Swift would `malloc` when what I am doing is basically

```
let myArray = [foo, bar, baz ...] // 1'000'000 instances of a class
for item in myArray {
    ...
}
```

It seems like this should be just a read access?

Comment: You've simplified this example too much, we don't have much to work off of.

Comment: [Some more context here](https://www.reddit.com/r/swift/comments/dpppwk/why_is_iterating_over_an_array_so_expensive_in/f5xbup1/). It might matter that the array type is generic.